# How to handle while throwing multiple custom exception

Tags: java, exception

From a single method trowing two different custom exceptions based on the condition. While creating a custom exception passing two things one is an error message and another one is error code as a string. But I'm unable to get the error based on the error code. getting an error while calling processErrorCodes() method. Could anyone please help me in fixing this.

```
// BackgroundException is a custom EXCEPTION 
public class BackgroundException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4664456874499611218L;

        private String errorCode="Unknown_Exception";

        public BackgroundException(String message, String errorCode){
            super(message);
            this.errorCode=errorCode;
        }

        public String getErrorCode(){
            return this.errorCode;
        }    
}

// Similarly I have InvalidException custom exception

public class MyExceptionTest {

public void methodTest(){
    String policyId =null;
    String policyNotification = null;
    String policyStatus = null;
    try {
        if(policyNotification !=null) {

            if(policyStatus!=null) {

                if(policyId!=null) {    

                }
                else{
                    throw new InvalidException("Policy ID Is Null","POLICY_ID");
                }

            }else{
                throw new BackgroundException("Policy Status Is Null","POLICY_STATUS");
            }
        }
        else{
            throw new BackgroundException("Policy Notification Is Null","POLICY_NOTIFICATION");
        }
    } catch (BackgroundException | InvalidException e  ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        try {
            processErrorCodes(e);
        } catch (MyExcep e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.getMessage();
    }

}
private static void processErrorCodes(Exception e) throws BackgroundException,InvalidException {
    switch(e.getErrorCode()){
    case "POLICY_NOTIFICATION":
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    case "POLICY_ID":
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    case "POLICY_STATUS":
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    default:
        System.out.println("Unknown exception occured, lets log it for further debugging."+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyExceptionTest mt = new MyExceptionTest(); 
     mt.methodTest();
}
}

I just want to handle those exceptions based on the error code.
```

Comment: You declared exception in your method parameter as `Exception e` and `getErrorCode` method is not declared in `Exception` class. You would have to use `instanceof` to check(for safety) and downcast.

Comment: You should also be using enums (or just subclasses of the exception type) instead of magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need a common superclass for all your custom exceptions, let say `MessageCodeException`, extending `Exception` and the accept this super class type as a parameter inside of your `processErrorCodes` method

```
public abstract class MessageCodeException extends Exception {
    public abstract String getCode();

    // you can have a same abstract method for message
}

public class BackgroundException extends MessageCodeException {
    // ...
}

public class InvalidException extends MessageCodeException {
    // ...
}

//and now the process method will look like

private static void processErrorCodes(Exception e) throws ... {
    // ...
}
```

That's abvious that for current implementation you cannot access `code` field, because `Exception` class interface does not provide anything like this

---

BTW it seems to be very bad idea to create Exception driven business validation logic. Wouldn't it be better to create some kind of `ValidationResult` object with list (lists) of errors/warning/successes and to process such validation result at the end? The purpose of the `Exception` existence is not to control application flow, but to force user to provide some support for critical situations (or to handle somehow unexpected situations with `RuntimeException`)